# How to have Circle ripple effect on an IconButton?

Tags: button, dart, flutter, icons

I would like to make a button with a circular ripple effect using an Icon, I've seen something online but I can't do it. It is not that straight forward like it should be. Trying with this code now.

```
InkWell(
    onTap: () {},
    splashColor: Colors.red,
    highlightColor: Colors.white,
    child: new Icon(
        FontAwesomeIcons.chevronCircleUp,
        size: 100,
    ),
)
```

Another try was with this, but I cannot understand why those don't perfectly centers with each other.

```
Container(
    margin: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
    height: 100.0,
    width: 100.0,
    child: new RaisedButton(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
        elevation: 100.0,
        color: Colors.black,
        highlightElevation: 0.0,
        onPressed: () {},
        splashColor: Colors.red,
        highlightColor: Colors.red,
        //shape: RoundedRectangleBorder e tutto il resto uguale
        shape: CircleBorder(
            side: BorderSide(color: Colors.black, width: 5),
        ),
        child: Icon(
            FontAwesomeIcons.chevronCircleUp,
            color: Colors.white.withOpacity(.8),
            size: 80,
        ),
    ),
),
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: Can you edit your question with an example of what you're looking for?

Comment: I just want the ripple effect to be applied in circular way not squared like it is now. And I dont understand why in the second code it doesn't perfectly center the child.

Answer (score 32):

I see that you'd like granular controll over the size of the ripple.
I ended up using the code below.

```
Padding(
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
    child: InkWell(
        customBorder: new CircleBorder(),
        onTap: () {},
        splashColor: Colors.red,
        child: new Icon(
            Icons.arrow_back,
            size: 24,
            color: Colors.black,
        ),
    ),
)
```

The InkWell effect renders a square, however using `CircleBorder` crops it to a circular shape.

By default the effect attempts to fill the space, so to modify the size I added padding on all sides, cropping the effect. If you are still having trouble with the ripple effect not rendering at all, wrapping your code in a `Material()` should fix most issues, or taking a look at the app theme.

Comment: `customBorder: CircleBorder()` it is the real concise solution

Comment: I would add that `Material` is a requirement if ripple renders somewhere below, like in case with `TextField` using `filled=true` decoration.

Answer (score 19):

It worked for me , All above solution made a square shadow not circle

```
 Material(
              color: Colors.transparent,
                shape: CircleBorder(),
                clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
        child : Icon() )
```

Answer (score 10):

Wrap your `InkWell` widget with `Material` widget and `material` widget should have a color.

```
 Material( color: Colors.transparent,
 child: InkWell( onTap: () { print("tapped"); }, ) );
```

Comment: Can you tell me why in the second code they don't centers perfectly too?

Comment: Also the ripple effect is applied to a squared box not in circle like I woul like.

Comment: @FlorisMarpepa: Ink effect starts from the position of touch, not from the center.

Answer (score 9):

You can simply use a **RawMaterialButton** with `constraints` and `shape` properties **to create a icon with tint color and circular background**.
Also you can disable `shape` property to have a rectangular button.

**Note:**
Here I used a [SVG Plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_svg) to use my desired **SVG** icon (placed in assets/icons folder), but you can simply use any `Icon` widget instead of it also.

Example:

```
RawMaterialButton(
  onPressed: () {}, //do your action
  elevation: 1.0,
  constraints: BoxConstraints(), //removes empty spaces around of icon
  shape: CircleBorder(), //circular button
  fillColor: Color(0xffff6464), //background color 
  splashColor: Colors.amber, 
  highlightColor: Colors.amber, 
  child: SvgPicture.asset(
    "assets/icons/heart.svg",
    width: 24,
    height: 24,
  ),
  padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
)
```

[image]

Comment: if don't use (constraints) ,  Since the width of the Flutter is set to 88.0 by default, be careful to follow this answer.

Answer (score 8):

In the first code snippet, the one that you wrapped in `InkWell`,the effect is not circular, I guess you want the circular effect.

You can directly use `IconButton`, rather than wrapping it with `InkWell`.

```
IconButton(
        icon: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.chevronCircleUp),
        iconSize: 100,
        onPressed: () {},
        splashColor: Colors.blue,
      ),
```

[image: Effect gif]

Comment: Yes i've tried this way but it doesn't work. I just copied and pasted your exact code and it only shows the icon, no ripple effect at all.

Comment: Okay, does this gif have the same effect that you are trying to achieve though? @FlorisMarpepa

Comment: yes, but how can you set the dimensions of the effect? However don't know why it doesn't work with me but yes with you. I just copied pasted the code..

Comment: I think you have to have a MaterialApp widget as an ancestors to use some of the material design features. Is that the case?

As far as I know IconButton has no properties related to the dimensions of the effect by the way. It just starts from where you tap and go circular.

Comment: My page is the home of the MaterialApp, i tried to wrap your code in a Material. It gives me the effect but a white square in the background too. So I made the color argument = Colors.transparent, now ok but the ripple goes square not round

Material(
                      color: Colors.transparent,
                      child: IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.chevronCircleUp),
                        iconSize: 100,
                        onPressed: () {},
                        splashColor: Colors.blue,
                      ),
                    ),

Comment: I think if you have a container with a background set, the ripple is behind this background. That is as far as I figured it out

Comment: Just wrap `IconButton` with `Material` widget.

Comment: Damn. I totally have forgot about IconButtons lol

Answer (score 4):

I used a FAB without background.

```
FloatingActionButton(
  onPressed: () {},
  backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
  mini: true,
  child: Icon(
    Icons.more_vert,
    color: Colors.white,
  ),
)
```

Comment: add "elevation: 0.0" to remove the shadow.

Answer (score 3):

```
Material(
  child: IconButton(
    icon: Icon(
      FontAwesomeIcons.search,
    ),
    onPressed: () {},
  ),
)
```

Adding Material Widget as paret works for me

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 2):

```
            CircleAvatar(
                backgroundColor: Colors.grey[200],
                child: IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.search,
                    color: Colors.black,
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {},
                ),
              ),
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/3782

If it doesn't work for you with IconButton, here is the explanation.

TLDR: Don't set background to your parent container and let Material do it's job drawing ripple on the background.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap it Material widget with transparent background color:

```
Container(
    child:Material(
        color: Colors.transparent
        child: IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.heart),
            onPressed: (){}
        ),
    ),
);
```

Source link: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/61811#issuecomment-660630611

Comment: This will look square and ugly. This answer has better design taste.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/72701928/2415921

Answer (score 0):

I was having issues with the ripple effect not working for the IconButton answer and also for the Inkwell answer.

It turned out to be nothing to do with background colors, but something in my onPressed handler was cancelling the ripple effect. Maybe another animation.

This could be confirmed by putting a 200ms delay inside onPressed, and the ripple effect came back.

Comment: This solution does not have optimal performance. Solutions that turn the button into a round shape are better.

Answer (score 0):

If you need circular widget and circular ripple effect, try this:

```
ClipOval(
          child: Material(
            type: MaterialType.transparency,
            child: InkWell(
              onTap: () {},
              child: Ink(
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.red,
                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                ),
                child: const SizedBox(width: 100, height: 100,),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        )
```